# Get unc path gives access denied error for user without admin permissions

Tags: vb6, filesystems, unc

I am using code given in [this link](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/UncName/) to get UNC path of a file.

It works only if a user has admin Admin Privileges. Otherwise it gives access denied error. What is the reason for it? Is there any alternative or solutions?

Comment: If you just need to convert a drive-letter remote path to a UNC path you can rip out a lot of his code and admin rights aren't needed.  But to convert a local path to a UNC path is tougher and requires enumerating shares (for which you need admin rights) and some coin-flipping since a given path can be encompassed within more than one share.